# UISearchBar slides away when tapped

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uinavigationbar, uisearchbar

I have a search bar as a title view for my navigation bar.

And it looks like this, the way I want it to look like:

[image: Search bar before tapping]

But when I tap on it, it just slides to top and becomes inaccessible

[image]

Here is the code I used to configure it:

```
- (void)configureSearchBar
{
    self.searchController = [[UISearchController alloc] initWithSearchResultsController:nil];
    self.searchController.searchBar.delegate = self;
    self.navigationItem.titleView = self.searchController.searchBar;
}
```

Is there any way to fix this kind of problem?

Comment: Have you implemented notification methods `-(void) keyboardWillShow:(NSNotification *)notification` ? or you are changing the frame of your searchbar in any of its delegate methods.

Comment: @ShehzadAli keyboard is shown as long as search bar is visible. I mean there is a brief moment after the tap, when the search bar moves up. When the search bar slides completely, the keyboard disappears too. So I think there is no need to implement this method.

Comment: Remove this line and see what happens `self.searchController = [[UISearchController alloc] initWithSearchResultsController:nil];`

Comment: @J.Lopes The search bar has disappeared.

Comment: Is `configureSearchBar` all your code about the searchbar? Have you tried log the searchController frame? `NSLog(@"%@", NSStringFromCGRect(@"FRAME HERE"));`?

Comment: I've found the answer. All I needed was to just set `self.searchController.hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation ` to `NO`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
self.searchController.hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation = NO
```

Adding this line has solved this problem or me. The reason of this problem was that my search bar was set as a title view for my navigation bar and the property `hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation` was set to `YES` by default. Setting this property to `NO` solves this kind of problem.